# How to make gps permission optional?

Tags: android, permissions

My app have gps support.
In code I have check for GPS hardware availability.
Unfortunately on market people without gps can not install my app.
How to make use ot GPS optional so users can instal it even when there is no GPS on device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:required="false"` to your Permission in the manifest

e.g.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: You mean user have to accept permission if have GPS and this permision wouldn't be required if user doesn't have gps?

Comment: @Kostadin permission acceptance by user is all or none. The required='false' means that devices that don't have a gps will see your app.

Comment: android:required="false" is for 'uses-feature'. So it is enough to use 'uses-feature' and 'android:required="false"' - to prevent filtering and user have in both cases to agree with permission?

Comment: @Kostadin Yes, that will be sufficient. You are also correct that `android:required="false"` needs to be set on the `<uses-feature>` tag, as shown in user1762832's answer.

Comment: Do you need to remove previous <uses-permission> tags or do you you use this line together in conjunction with uses-permission lines?

Comment: @AlexVPerl They should work along side use-permission lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

in your manifest file.